# How to include a new function in sklearn library

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am looking to write a function on a new type of classification model and include it in sklearn (so I could share it with the world!). How do I do this? Is there a link that shows me the all the steps and guidelines I should follow? I am looking to write the function in a similar "form" to existing classification models in sklearn, such as .fit(X,Y), .predict(X) etc. so that the "form" is standardised.

Comment: You should post your question here instead: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues

Comment: Ok thanks I will have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sklearn provides an API that probably contains what you are looking for.

You can find the details at: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html

Comment: Ok thanks. I had a look at it. Got a bit confused. I could see there is a template but not too sure if I am interpreting it correctly. If you know of any other more “user friendly” site with working examples, please let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: @Leockl sorry, not familiar with anything specific. A quick Google search for "create custom sklearn estimator" seems to return some potential options. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Biggus will do. Will also check out the forum as suggested by YOLO.